# Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have to create a report on some student completions. The students each belong to one client. Here are the tables (simplified for this question).

```
CREATE TABLE  `clients` (
  `clientId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `clientName` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `courseNames` varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''
)
```

The `courseNames` field holds a comma-delimited string of course names, eg "AB01,AB02,AB03"

```
CREATE TABLE  `clientenrols` (
  `clientEnrolId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `studentId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `courseId` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
)
```

The `courseId` field here is **the index of the course name in the clients.courseNames field**. So, if the client's `courseNames` are "AB01,AB02,AB03", and the `courseId` of the enrolment is `2`, then the student is in AB03.

Is there a way that I can do a single select on these tables that includes the course name? Keep in mind that there will be students from different clients (and hence have different course names, not all of which are sequential,eg: "NW01,NW03")

Basically, if I could split that field and return a single element from the resulting array, that would be what I'm looking for. Here's what I mean in magical pseudocode:

```
SELECT e.`studentId`, SPLIT(",", c.`courseNames`)[e.`courseId`]
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

MySQL's only string-splitting function is [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). You can use this, to, for example:

- Return the item before the first separator in a string:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 1);
  +--------------------------------------------+
  | SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 1) |
  +--------------------------------------------+
  | foo                                        |
  +--------------------------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- Return the item after the last separator in a string:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', -1);
  +---------------------------------------------+
  | SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', -1) |
  +---------------------------------------------+
  | qux                                         |
  +---------------------------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- Return everything before the third separator in a string:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 3);
  +--------------------------------------------+
  | SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 3) |
  +--------------------------------------------+
  | foo#bar#baz                                |
  +--------------------------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- Return the second item in a string, by chaining two calls:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 2), '#', -1);
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo#bar#baz#qux', '#', 2), '#', -1) |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | bar                                                                  |
  +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```

In general, a simple way to get the nth element of a `#`-separated string (assuming that you know it definitely has at least n elements) is to do:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_string, '#', n), '#', -1);
```

The inner `SUBSTRING_INDEX` call discards the nth separator and everything after it, and then the outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX` call discards everything except the final element that remains.

If you want a more robust solution that returns `NULL` if you ask for an element that doesn't exist (for instance, asking for the 5th element of `'a#b#c#d'`), then you can [count the delimiters using `REPLACE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344881/1709587) and then conditionally return `NULL` using [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
IF(
    LENGTH(your_string) - LENGTH(REPLACE(your_string, '#', '')) / LENGTH('#') < n - 1,
    NULL,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_string, '#', n), '#', -1)
)
```

Of course, this is pretty ugly and hard to understand! So you might want to wrap it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION split(string TEXT, delimiter TEXT, n INT)
RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN IF(
    (LENGTH(string) - LENGTH(REPLACE(string, delimiter, ''))) / LENGTH(delimiter) < n - 1,
    NULL,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimiter, n), delimiter, -1)
);
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
mysql> SELECT SPLIT('foo,bar,baz,qux', ',', 3);
+----------------------------------+
| SPLIT('foo,bar,baz,qux', ',', 3) |
+----------------------------------+
| baz                              |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT SPLIT('foo,bar,baz,qux', ',', 5);
+----------------------------------+
| SPLIT('foo,bar,baz,qux', ',', 5) |
+----------------------------------+
| NULL                             |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT SPLIT('foo###bar###baz###qux', '###', 2);
+------------------------------------------+
| SPLIT('foo###bar###baz###qux', '###', 2) |
+------------------------------------------+
| bar                                      |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 32):

Until now, I wanted to keep those comma separated lists in my SQL db - well aware of all warnings!

I kept thinking that they have benefits over lookup tables (which provide a way to a normalized data base). After some days of refusing, **I've seen the light**:

- Using lookup tables is NOT causing more code than those ugly string operations when using comma separated values in one field.
- The lookup table allows for native number formats and is thus NOT bigger than those csv fields. It is SMALLER though.
- The involved string operations are slim in high level language code (SQL and PHP), but expensive compared to using arrays of integers.
- Databases are not meant to be human readable, and it is mostly stupid to try to stick to structures due to their readability / direct editability, as I did.

In short, there is a reason why there is no native SPLIT() function in MySQL.

Comment: I use to work this when the user filters data input made by himself. ie when you have an open question like "accepted extensions" then the user needs to filter a criteria. To save related data the best is - as you said - to use a separated related table

Comment: there is no way to pass an array to a mysql stored routine... so What I do now if there is no way to pass a text and split in the routine?! (

Comment: Yeah, OK, **however**: _my_ purpose in wanting a SPLIT() de-aggregation function is to normalize data that are not currently normalized, so that I can keep them in a normalized format in the future! If your comment is correct, then MySQL's lack of this function is impeding my progress in normalizing my data! It's very odd and asymmetrical if MySQL provides a **GROUP_CONCAT()** function, but not a corresponding inverse: SPLIT() function! Looks like I'll have to botch a "solution" together with SUBSTRING_INDEX() instead!

Comment: Read this feature set of MySQL as: If your data is in the base, it's already too late. Take care of normalization by design /before/ inserting.
Normalization on /reading/ data is none of our business.
Again, that's just what i've learned from it.

Comment: "why there is no native SPLIT() function in MySQL"
I expect the answer is because functions return a single value. And a Split() by definition returns multiple values (traditionally an array).
A stored procedure perhaps? But then you need to do something with the output...

Comment: @Melchior Blausand: I have this problem right now. I don't know about you, but I very rarely design the databases I need to query. I'm not the person who put the data in there. I have no control over their design. This is the case for over 90% of the databases I query.

Comment: The question was different, regardless - lookup table to cause difficulties when over used, and also consume server resources. Should be used only when stored Ids are really in high volumes

Comment: Such function exist in MS SQL, I guess they still haven't seen the light. What would you do if you want to pass a record with 62 columns and then have a single column one->many record attached to it and want to insert it in one go, specially using a procedure?

Answer (score 26):

Seeing that it's a fairly popular question - the answer is YES.

For a column `column` in table `table` containing all of your coma separated values:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val CHAR(255));
SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT  `column`) AS data FROM `table`), ",", "'),('"),"');");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
SELECT DISTINCT(val) FROM temp;
```

---

Please remember however to **not** store CSV in your DB

---

Per @Mark Amery - as this translates coma separated values into an `INSERT` statement, be careful when running it on unsanitised data

---

Just to reiterate, please **don't** store CSV in your DB; this function is meant to translate CSV into sensible DB structure and not to be used anywhere in your code. If you have to use it in production, please rethink your DB structure

Comment: I have a horrible column containing pipe-separated data (instead of commas) but the combination of parentheses you used, and the fact that commas are being replaced, has made that second line so difficult to breakdown, I can't rewrite it for pipes instead of comma replace.

Comment: @BadHorsie - `SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT  \`column\`) AS data FROM \`table\`), "|", "'),('"),"');");`

Comment: Thanks, I managed it. It's easier to see in Stackoverflow's syntax highlighting. phpMyAdmin is not very good syntax highlighting.

Comment: -1; good lord, what is this madness? This will fail if the values in `table` contain quotes, possibly exposing you to SQL injections.

Comment: @MarkAmery You can use [QUOTE(column)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) before REPLACE and remove the first and the last single-quotes. See [example](http://rextester.com/LLQE29328)

Answer (score 15):

You can create a function for this:

```
/**
* Split a string by string (Similar to the php function explode())
*
* @param VARCHAR(12) delim The boundary string (delimiter).
* @param VARCHAR(255) str The input string.
* @param INT pos The index of the string to return
* @return VARCHAR(255) The (pos)th substring
* @return VARCHAR(255) Returns the [pos]th string created by splitting the str parameter on boundaries formed by the delimiter.
* @{@example
*     SELECT SPLIT_STRING('|', 'one|two|three|four', 1);
*     This query
* }
*/
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SPLIT_STRING;
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(delim VARCHAR(12), str VARCHAR(255), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN
    REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1
        ),
        delim, ''
    );
```

Converting the magical pseudocode to use this, you would have:

```
SELECT e.`studentId`, SPLIT_STRING(',', c.`courseNames`, e.`courseId`)
FROM...
```

Comment: Please be aware that the above code won't work for multi byte characters like UTF-8. I think using CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH should do the trick.

Answer (score 12):

Based on Alex answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022431/1466341) I came up with even better solution. Solution which doesn't contain exact one record ID.

Assuming that the comma separated list is in table `data.list`, and it contains listing of codes from other table `classification.code`, you can do something like:

```
SELECT 
    d.id, d.list, c.code
FROM 
    classification c
    JOIN data d
        ON d.list REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', c.code, '[[:>:]]');
```

So if you have tables and data like this:

```
CLASSIFICATION (code varchar(4) unique): ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')
MY_DATA (id int, list varchar(255)): (100, 'C,A,B'), (150, 'B,A,D'), (200,'B')
```

above SELECT will return

```
(100, 'C,A,B', 'A'),
(100, 'C,A,B', 'B'),
(100, 'C,A,B', 'C'),
(150, 'B,A,D', 'A'),
(150, 'B,A,D', 'B'),
(150, 'B,A,D', 'D'),
(200, 'B', 'B'),
```

Comment: Edited to not use ',?' in regexp, but use word boundaries check `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]`. Otherwise from value "WEB" it can extract more than one value - like E or B or EB or WE (any combination).

Comment: In MySQL if it is a comma delimited field then it would might be more efficient to use FIND_IN_SET rather than a regular expression for the join.

Comment: @Kickstart probably you're right, but can you please post full SELECT query with FIND_IN_SET to make your comment complete?

Comment: very old thread. But you could just use this for the ON clause . ON FIND_IN_SET(c.code, d.list) > 0

Answer (score 6):

Building on Alwin Kesler's solution, here's a bit of a more practical real world example.

Assuming that the comma separated list is in my_table.list, and it's a listing of ID's for my_other_table.id, you can do something like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    my_other_table 
WHERE 
    (SELECT list FROM my_table WHERE id = '1234') REGEXP CONCAT(',?', my_other_table.id, ',?');
```

Comment: Nice solution, but how can we get rid of that id='1234' parameter? I mean, I want to extract values for all records of my_table not just one.

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved this kind of problem with a regular expression pattern. They tend to be slower than regular queries but it's an easy way to retrieve data in a comma-delimited query column

```
SELECT * 
FROM `TABLE`
WHERE `field` REGEXP ',?[SEARCHED-VALUE],?';
```

the greedy question mark helps to search at the beggining or the end of the string.

Hope that helps for anyone in the future

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to explode a string in a MySQL SELECT statement.

Firstly generate a series of numbers up to the largest number of delimited values you wish to explode. Either from a table of integers, or by unioning numbers together. The following generates 100 rows giving the values 1 to 100. It can easily be expanded to give larger ranges (add another sub query giving the values 0 to 9 for hundreds - hence giving 0 to 999, etc).

```
SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aNum
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
```

This can be cross joined against your table to give you the values. Note that you use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the delimited value up to a certain value, and then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get that value, excluding previous ones.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clients.courseNames, ',', sub0.aNum), ',', -1) AS a_course_name
FROM clients
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aNum, units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aSubscript
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
) sub0
```

As you can see there is a slight issue here that the last delimited value is repeated many times. To get rid of this you need to limit the range of numbers based on how many delimiters there are. This can be done by taking the length of the delimited field and comparing it to the length of the delimited field with the delimiters changed to '' (to remove them). From this you can get the number of delimiters:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clients.courseNames, ',', sub0.aNum), ',', -1) AS a_course_name
FROM clients
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aNum
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
) sub0
ON (1 + LENGTH(clients.courseNames) - LENGTH(REPLACE(clients.courseNames, ',', ''))) >= sub0.aNum
```

In the original example field you could (for example) count the number of students on each course based on this. Note that I have changed the sub query that gets the range of numbers to bring back 2 numbers, 1 is used to determine the course name (as these are based on starting at 1) and the other gets the subscript (as they are based starting at 0).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clients.courseNames, ',', sub0.aNum), ',', -1) AS a_course_name, COUNT(clientenrols.studentId)
FROM clients
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aNum, units.i + tens.i * 10 AS aSubscript
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
) sub0
ON (1 + LENGTH(clients.courseNames) - LENGTH(REPLACE(clients.courseNames, ',', ''))) >= sub0.aNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN clientenrols
ON clientenrols.courseId = sub0.aSubscript
GROUP BY a_course_name
```

As you can see, it is possible but quite messy. And with little opportunity to use indexes it is not going to be efficient. Further the range must cope with the greatest number of delimited values, and works by excluding lots of duplicates; if the max number of delimited values is very large then this will slow things down dramatically. Overall it is generally far better to just properly normalise the database.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way, have a link table, i.e.:

Table 1: clients, client info, blah blah blah

Table 2: courses, course info, blah blah

Table 3: clientid, courseid

Then do a JOIN and you're off to the races.

Comment: yeah, i'm now painfully aware of how poor a decision it was to go with the comma-separated list.

Comment: it's never too late to redesign :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  tab1.std_name, tab1.stdCode, tab1.payment,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(tab1.payment, '|', 1) as rupees,
  SUBSTRING(tab1.payment, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tab1.payment, '|', 1)) + 2,LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tab1.payment, '|', 2))) as date
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    si.std_name, hfc.stdCode,
    if(isnull(hfc.payDate), concat(hfc.coutionMoneyIn,'|', year(hfc.startDtae), '-',  monthname(hfc.startDtae)), concat(hfc.payMoney, '|', monthname(hfc.payDate), '-', year(hfc.payDate))) AS payment
  FROM hostelfeescollection hfc
  INNER JOIN hostelfeecollectmode hfm ON hfc.tranId = hfm.tranId
  INNER JOIN student_info_1 si ON si.std_code = hfc.stdCode
  WHERE hfc.tranId = 'TRAN-AZZZY69454'
) AS tab1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need get table from string with delimiters:

```
SET @str = 'function1;function2;function3;function4;aaa;bbbb;nnnnn';
SET @delimeter = ';';
SET @sql_statement = CONCAT('SELECT '''
                ,REPLACE(@str, @delimeter, ''' UNION ALL SELECT ''')
                ,'''');
SELECT @sql_statement;
SELECT 'function1' UNION ALL SELECT 'function2' UNION ALL SELECT 'function3' UNION ALL SELECT 'function4' UNION ALL SELECT 'aaa' UNION ALL SELECT 'bbbb' UNION ALL SELECT 'nnnnn'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Search in a column containing comma-separated values

MySQL has a dedicated function [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) that returns field index if the value is found in a string containing comma-separated values.

For example, the following statement returns one-based index of value `C` in string `A,B,C,D`.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('C', 'A,B,C,D') AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
```

If the given value is not found, `FIND_IN_SET()` function returns `0`.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('Z', 'A,B,C,D') AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the above logic but modified it slightly. 
My input is of format :
"apple:100|pinapple:200|orange:300" stored in a variable @updtAdvanceKeyVal

Here is the function block :

```
set @res = "";

set @i = 1;
set @updtAdvanceKeyVal = updtAdvanceKeyVal;

REPEAT


 -- set r =  replace(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@updtAdvanceKeyVal, "|", @i),
 --  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@updtAdvanceKeyVal, "|", @i -1)) + 1),"|","");

-- wrapping the function in "replace" function as above causes to cut off a character from
 -- the 2nd splitted value if the value is more than 3 characters. Writing it in 2 lines causes no such problem and the output is as expected
-- sample output by executing the above function :
-- orange:100
-- pi apple:200    !!!!!!!!strange output!!!!!!!!
-- tomato:500

      set @r =  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@updtAdvanceKeyVal, "|", @i),
                  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@updtAdvanceKeyVal, "|", @i -1)) + 1);

      set @r = replace(@r,"|","");

      if @r <> "" then

              set @key = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@r, ":",1);
              set @val = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@r, ":",-1);

              select @key, @val;
      end if;

      set @i = @i + 1;

     until @r = ""
END REPEAT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue with a field like that which I solved a different way. My use case was needing to take those ids in a comma separated list for use in a join.

I was able to solve it using a like, but it was made easier because in addition to the comma delimiter the ids were also quoted like so:

`keys
"1","2","6","12"`

Because of that, I was able to do a LIKE

`SELECT twwf.id, jtwi.id joined_id
FROM table_with_weird_field twwf
  INNER JOIN join_table_with_ids jtwi 
    ON twwf.delimited_field LIKE CONCAT("%\"", jtwi.id, "\"%")`

This basically just looks to see if the id from the table you're trying to join appears in the set and at that point you can join on it easily enough and return your records. You could also just create a view from something like this.

It worked well for my use case where I was dealing with a Wordpress plugin that managed relations in the way described. The quotes really help though because otherwise you run the risk of partial matches (aka - id 1 within 18, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JSON in more recent MySQL versions. It's a blast. We will have a quick preparation to create a numbers table. Then first we create an intermediary table to convert the comma delimited strings into a json array then we will use `json_extract` to blast them apart. I am encapsulating the strings in quotes carefully escaping existing quotes because I had semicolon separated strings containing commas.

So to create the numbers table, hopefully you have more clients than courses, choose an adequately big table if not.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO numbers 
SELECT @row := @row + 1
FROM clients JOIN (select @row:=0) t2;
```

Add LIMIT 50 if you know you only have 50 courses. Now, that was easy, wasn't it? Now on to the real work, honestly it's the quotes that make it uglier but at least it's more generic that way:

```
CREATE TABLE json_coursenames 
SELECT clientId,clientName,CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPLACE(courseName,'"','\\"'), ',', '","'), '"]') AS a
FROM clients;

CREATE TABLE extracted
SELECT clientId,clientName,REPLACE(TRIM(TRIM('"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(a, concat('$[', n, ']')))), '\\"', '"')
FROM json_coursenames
INNER JOIN numbers ON n < JSON_LENGTH(a);
```

Wheee!

The meat here are these two: the `CONCAT('["', REPLACE(coursename, ',', '","'), '"]')` (I dropped the second `REPLACE` to make it more visible) will convert `foo,bar,bar` into `"foo","bar","baz"`. The other trick is `JSON_EXTRACT(a, concat('$[', n, ']')` will become `JSON_EXTRACT(a, $[12])` and that's the 13th element in the array, see [JSON Path syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

SQL：

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT *
FROM
    JSON_TABLE(
        concat('["',replace('AB01,AB02,AB03',',','","'),'"]'),
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS(
            Value VARCHAR(50) PATH '$'
            )
        ) data
WHERE Value != '';
```

RESULT：
|  | Value |
| -------- | :-------------- |
| 1   | AB01            |
| 2   | AB02            |
| 3   | AB03            |

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using `FIND_IN_SET` and a number of subqueries for a one-liner. A previous dev stored data comma-separated strings in a table for some reason:

```
| org_id | applicable_domains |  
| 1  | domain1.com,domain2.com |
```

Using `FIND_IN_SET`, I can check if a value exists in that comma-separated string and match it with another table:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('domain1.com', (SELECT applicable_domains FROM org_domains WHERE org_id = 1))
```

The dataset returned will return a value > 0 if the value is in the comma-separated list, or a 0 if not. I can specify a domain like I did here, domain1.com, or I can reference a column from another table to compare against:

```
SELECT user_id FROM ( \  
SELECT user_id, FIND_IN_SET(user_domain, ( \  
SELECT applicable_domains FROM org_domains WHERE org_id = 1)) AS 'found' FROM users) AS temp WHERE temp.found > 0
```

It's not pretty, but assigning a value of > 0 with FIND_IN_SET then allows you to filter that dataset down to only hits and query against another table. The first subquery pulls the comma-separated data from a table. The second subquery assigns a value > 0 if the data matches. The grandfather query filters that data down and removes values if they have a 0.
**NOTE** Please do not store data comma-separated like the yahoo that built this table originally..

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you do it for SQL Server. Someone else can translate it to MySQL. [Parsing CSV Values Into Multiple Rows](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows).

```
SELECT Author, 
NullIf(SubString(',' + Phrase + ',' , ID , CharIndex(',' , ',' + Phrase + ',' , ID) - ID) , '') AS Word 
FROM Tally, Quotes 
WHERE ID <= Len(',' + Phrase + ',') AND SubString(',' + Phrase + ',' , ID - 1, 1) = ',' 
AND CharIndex(',' , ',' + Phrase + ',' , ID) - ID > 0
```

The idea is to cross join to a predefined table Tally which contains integer 1 through 8000 (or whatever big enough number) and run `SubString` to find the right ,word, position.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've got so far (found it on the page [Ben Alpert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49485) mentioned):

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.`courseNames`, ',', e.`courseId` + 1)
        , LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.`courseNames`, ',', e.`courseId`)
    ) + 1)
    , ','
    , ''
)
FROM `clients` c INNER JOIN `clientenrols` e USING (`clientId`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, nothing I used worked, so I decided creating a real simple split function, hope it helps:

```
    DECLARE inipos INTEGER;
    DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
    DECLARE maxlen INTEGER;
    DECLARE item VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE delim VARCHAR(1);

    SET delim = '|';
    SET inipos = 1;
    SET fullstr = CONCAT(fullstr, delim);
    SET maxlen = LENGTH(fullstr);

    REPEAT
        SET endpos = LOCATE(delim, fullstr, inipos);
        SET item =  SUBSTR(fullstr, inipos, endpos - inipos);

        IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN           
            USE_THE_ITEM_STRING;
        END IF;
        SET inipos = endpos + 1;
    UNTIL inipos >= maxlen END REPEAT;
```