# Find intersection of MySQL JSON objects or arrays

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

The question is about [MySQL/MariaDB JSON Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions/).
How do you find intersection of multiple JSON structures?
In PHP it is done using this code:

```
array_intersect(
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['b', 'c']
);
```

If we imagine a function named JSON_INTERSECT, the code would look like this:

```
SET @json1 = '{"key1": "a", "key2": "b"}';
SET @json2 = '["b", "c"]';
SET @json3 = '["c", "d"]';

SELECT JSON_INTERSECT(@json1, @json2); // returns '["b"]';
SELECT JSON_INTERSECT(@json1, @json3); // returns NULL;
```

Comment: Please explain the structure of you sql tables

Comment: @Dimgold No tables. The question has been updated with more details.

Comment: I believe that sql doesnt parse arrays you need to set a function that compares arraystrings using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099469/mysql-select-like-or-regexp-to-match-multiple-words-in-one-record) or [delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914199/split-strings-using-mysql)

Comment: [Feature was requested](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26182). Watch and/or vote on the issue to make its priority known.

Answer (score 4):

It looks there are no good built-in ways of doing this and there are still no good answers on this topic, so I thought I'd add my quick & dirty solution. If you execute the below code it will create a function called MY_JSON_INTERSECT that will output results exactly as the original poster specified. Make sure you've looked this over and are ok with creating a new function before trusting my code:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION `MY_JSON_INTERSECT`(Array1 VARCHAR(1024), Array2 VARCHAR(1024)) RETURNS varchar(1024)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x int;
    DECLARE val, output varchar(1024);
    SET output = '[]';
    SET x = 0;
    IF JSON_LENGTH(Array2) < JSON_LENGTH(Array1) THEN
        SET val = Array2;
        SET Array2 = Array1;
        SET Array1 = val;
    END IF;
    WHILE x < JSON_LENGTH(Array1) DO
        SET val = JSON_EXTRACT(Array1, CONCAT('$[',x,']'));
        IF JSON_CONTAINS(Array2,val) THEN
            SET output = JSON_MERGE(output,val);
        END IF;
        SET x = x + 1; 
    END WHILE;
    IF JSON_LENGTH(output) = 0 THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RETURN output;
    END IF;
END$$
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
SELECT MY_JSON_INTERSECT('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]','[0,3,5,7,9]');
```

Outputs:

```
[3,5,7]
```

This isn't beautiful or efficient, but it's something that works... Hopefully better answers will come soon.

Answer (score 1):

With `JSON_TABLE` which is available since MySQL 8, the following SQL can produce the intersection of two json arrays:

```sql
SET @json2 = '["b", "c"]';
SET @json3 = '["c", "d"]';

SELECT DISTINCT t1.val
FROM
JSON_TABLE(@json2, '$[*]' COLUMNS(val VARCHAR(50) PATH '$')) t1
INNER JOIN JSON_TABLE(@json3, '$[*]' COLUMNS(val VARCHAR(50) PATH '$')) t2
ON t1.val = t2.val;
```

It unnests the two json arrays into two temp tables, and return the intersection by inner join on the same values.

But when the input array contains same elements (not a set), the result may be not as expected. Based on the expectation, you can change the `DISTINCT` part as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 11.2 added [JSON_ARRAY_INTERSECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_array_intersect/) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

```
SET @json1= '[1,2,3]';
SET @json2= '[1,2,4]';

SELECT json_array_intersect(@json1, @json2); 
+--------------------------------------+
| json_array_intersect(@json1, @json2) |
+--------------------------------------+
| [1, 2]                               |
+--------------------------------------+
```