# Function resembling the work of Explode in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, explode

Is there any function in MySQL to explode data of a column and then retrieve it?
Like if a column data is P:12 , then can the data be exploded on ':' and then read?

Comment: It seems this question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: Not an answer to your Q but you should always try to keep only a single piece of data in any one field/record. In this case, how about storing the P seperately from the 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are many discussion about the `SPLIT` problem in mysql :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Split function in MYSQL check this [link](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

From the Link

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Usage

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
```

Example

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('a|bb|ccc|dd', '|', 3) as third;

+-------+
| third |
+-------+
| ccc   |
+-------+
```