# Mysql IN statement only find the first element in the list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `table` and one of the rows in `table` has a value like this: `6,7,8,9`

I want to select this row and this is the code I expect to work:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 8 IN (column)`

It doesn't work. However the code which works confuses me:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 6 IN (column)`

I tried with several values and found out that only the first element of the list is working.

How can this be?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10953029/259457). I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are comparing number with string. `6,7,8,9` cast to number will be `6`, so it will be true when do `6 IN (column)`.

You need to use `FIND_IN_SET` function:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8, `column`);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i love you