# select query to perform data existance in other table where data need to split and each part need to check

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I dont want to use any function or any procedure.

I want simple select query to check the existance of the each part of string.

like i have one table dummy which have name column

```
                         Id     name 
                          1   as;as;as
                          2    asd;rt
```

and child table

```
                       child_id       name
                          23           as
                          24           asd
                          25           rt
```

so any i can do that

i have tried like

```
select substr(first_name,1,instr(first_name,';')-1) from dummy;
select substr(first_name,instr(first_name,';')+1,instr(first_name,';')-1) 
                                                               from dummy;
```

Which is giving only first/second part but other part
how to get other part

Comment: What RDBMs you are using? SQL Server?MySQL? ORacle? etc..

Comment: If you're using MySQL, this may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: Why the limitation on using functions?  If you need to expand a delimited string into a series of values a function is the best way to do it.

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you need to separate your first name or what?

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right - You need to join these tables if child's NAME is included in a DUMMY.Name

[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8194c/3)

```
select t1.*, 
       t2.child_id, 
        t2.name as t2name 
from t1
left join t2 on (';'||t1.name||';' like '%;'||t2.name||';%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information on this question. We do not know if you have to detect more than one of the possible strings on just one field.

You could use three like clauses for the three possible scenarios

1. LIKE column_name ||'%;'
2. LIKE '%;'|| column_name
3. LIKE ';%'|| column_name ||'%;'

But it would probably work better for the future learning about building regular expressions. Here is a webpage that helped me a lot: [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/)