# PHP MySql: explode and JOIN Combination

Tags: php, mysql, join, explode

I put user id with separate comma in `MySql TABLE` for best user. `Example : 1,2,3` Now i work with `PHP` `explode()` function for this result:

```
$bestuser = explode(',',$bestuser);
```

i have another MySql TABLE for list of user with this row : id/name/datejoin/birthday ....

now, i need to print name of best user with MySql JOIN Methods. actually my mean how to combination explode result with other MySql TABLE result.

**NOTE**: i know this design(1,2,3) is bad, But I have no choice.

Comment: Why on earth would **you** *put user id with separate comma* and have *no choice*?! Ay caramba

Comment: because, i work with any module of cms and this module work with this method. I'm forced to this.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: Do I sense bad practice?

Comment: @eggyal: You right, i confess in my question.now, I'm looking for a solution for this.

Comment: As noted in the answer to which I linked, it is "*Hard to join the values to the lookup table they reference*" - which (if I've understood your question correctly) is what you're trying to do.  Bill Karwin *literally* wrote the book on this subject, so I'd probably pay attention when he tries to discourage using a certain pattern.  How is it that you *have no choice*?  Perhaps I've just been lucky, but I don't think I've ever found myself in a situation where there is literally no other choice: in my experience, there's almost always room for negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an SQL query to do this:

```
SELECT id,name
FROM user
WHERE id IN (:yourListOfIds)
```

Be cautious of SQL injection if the list is at any way user supplied.

Comment: Don't forget to mention what Database API you are using; furthermore, with the `:` dilema. don't forget to tell the OP about the binds, to accomplish this.

Comment: @Jim : what is it? `yourListOfIds`. how to put list of id?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query), but if you look at the comments on the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) you'll find lots of people talking about exploding.

Answer (score 0):

One *can* use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in the join criterion:

```sql
table_a JOIN table_b ON FIND_IN_SET(table_a.id_a, table_b.csv_a)
```

However (per the warnings in my comments above) this operation will be terribly inefficient, as MySQL must fully scan both tables.

A *much* better solution would be to create a table of relations:

```sql
CREATE TABLE relations (
  FOREIGN KEY (id_a) REFERENCES table_a (id_a),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_b) REFERENCES table_b (id_b)
) SELECT table_a.id_a, table_b.id_b
  FROM   table_a JOIN table_b
      ON FIND_IN_SET(table_a.id_a, table_b.csv_a);

ALTER TABLE table_b DROP csv_a;
```

Then one can query for required data by joining the tables as required:

```sql
SELECT   table_a.*
FROM     table_a JOIN relations USING (id_a)
WHERE    relations.id_b = ?
```

If so desired, one could even use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to obtain the original CSV:

```sql
SELECT   table_b.id_b, GROUP_CONCAT(relations.id_a) AS csv_a
FROM     table_b JOIN relations USING (id_b)
WHERE    ...
GROUP BY table_b.id_b
```