# Splitting delimited text and pairing with another field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, opencart

I hope this isn't a duplicate question, I have found many similar but none that match my requirements. I tried to get a solution with [Splitting mysql value into unknown number of parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755906/splitting-mysql-value-into-unknown-number-of-parts) but I think maybe I asked the wrong question - I specified not wanting to use php with that question. It also is close to [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query) but again, that doesn't quite define it. I installed [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) which looks like it will be a powerful tool but I can't get it return the result I wish. I have tried [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) in conjunction with [explode](http://php.net/explode) but I can't get all the data in the same array with it. Long preamble but here is the problem.
I have a DB with the following table.

`id`     `categories`

`100`   `|88|`

`102`   `|88|243|`

`442`   `|228|243|228|239|228|`

I'm restructing this to put it into OpenCart.

So need it like this or in an array that I can use to create this

`ID`   `category`

`100`   `88`

`102`   `88`

`102`   `243`

`442`   `228`

`442`   `243`

`442`   `228`

etc

I don't have a problem getting it into and out of the database, just amending the data to tie up the ID to each category however many there may be in the field. I have spent about 2 days trying to find a solution and I'm sure it's very basic.
The closest I've got is with `foreach`

but ended up with an array

```
array ('ID' => 442,
       'Category' => array (0 => 228, 1 => 243, 2 => 228 etc)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to normalize your data.

Comment: @ Ben Fortune - are you referring to the fact that `id 422` has `category 228` in it 3 times? I didn't notice that, but that is actual data from the DB - This has added a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're retrieving the query result, you could do something like this:

```
foreach($result as $row) { // iterate over each row in the query result

    $categories = array_filter(explode('|', $row['categories']));

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        // insert row into new table with id $row['id'] and category $category
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm calling it in as an array using SELECT id, categories FROM table. I need to read up on the range of array_... tools in php. I looked at array_walk and array_map but neither did the job I wanted. Thx.

Comment: @TimP Ok. If you're using PDO, `$result` would simply be the array returned by `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Could I enter it into the db on each iteration.? Avoiding reassignation? I know that would be massively inefficient in a production environment. But this is just a one time data conversion.

Comment: That was a response to a comment that has now disappeared. You have now commented in the code what I meant - insert row on each iteration.