# MySQL split string into rows through Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to Write a Stored Procedure IN MYSQL to convert given CSV string to rows.

```
E.g. Input String: 'str1,str2,str3,str4’

Output String: String
          ________
        str1
        str2
        str3
        str4
```

I had mssql snippet that im trying to convert to simple mysql procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CSVtoROWS(IN S VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
Declare  ISDefault varchar(20) DEFAULT '';
Declare str varchar(100);

set str= LTRIM(RTRIM(S));

IF(str = '')
   begin 
    SET ISDefault = 'string is empty';
    return(1);
end;
ELSE
    begin 
        SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Str
        FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(str, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Str ) AS A 
        CROSS APPLY Str.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
    end;
END;
```

Comment: In phpmyadmin it shows error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: The output needs to be cs values in one column distributed in each row..name of column is  strings

Comment: Perhaps you can take some ideas from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19756848).