# How do I return a single row for each value in a comma delimited field?

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement which fetches a value field on an ID

```
177,175,173,178,179
```

What is returned is anywhere from null, a single entry, to multiple comma delimited values in this field.

How can I use SQL to return 1 row for each value based on this comma delimited field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: do you mean that you want multiple row values to be concated with comma delimiter and you want all together under a single row.........

Comment: Don't store data like this. Consider normalizing the table and keeping every number in a separate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned in comments consider to normalize your data to be able to normally maintain and query your data.

In the meantime you achieve your goal in pure SQL with the help of tally(number) table which you can  create like this

```
CREATE TABLE tally (n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
  FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n;
```

Now your might look like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', n), ',', -1) value
  FROM table1 CROSS JOIN tally
 WHERE id = 1
   AND n <= 1 + (LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',', '')))
```

Output:

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|   177 |
|   175 |
|   173 |
|   178 |
|   179 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7048/2)** demo