# How to design table schema for storing values from <select multiple>

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select-multiple list html control, which enables end user to select multiple items. Currently, I stored user selected values as "truck, heavy truck, others" into mysql varchar field. But both truck and heavy truck are searched out if user select truck on select multiple control. SQL statement for this query is like "select truckType from table where trackType like '%truck%'".

Seems the only way for the solution is to put selected values into another table.

Is there any other way to handle this issue in one table?

Comment: lookup 'normalisation'

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry, what you mean?  I know normalisation.

Comment: "Currently, I stored user selected values as "truck, heavy truck, others" into mysql varchar field" - clearly not.

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree that the current design doesn't match normalisation. So I have to add additional table?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8585080/55787

Answer (score 0):

add  `,` to the end and start also

so value becomes `, truck, heavy truck, others,`

use this query

```
select truckType from table where trackType like '%, truck,%
```

NOTE: `,` in `like '%, truck,%'`

Comment: this doesn't work, both truck and heavy truck are searched out. Expected result is only truck rather than both.

Comment: @user2574853 sorry for that.I have edited the answer. you have to add `,` to start also.and then use above query.

Comment: anyway, this is not good since you don't know what values to be stored. For instance, only truck is in the field, you approach doesn't work. :-)

Comment: if you are gonna insert a new value the add `,` to the start and end.and if you are gonna update then update using `concat() method`

Comment: what if user selects truck and heavy truck from the select-multiple, which means he/she wants to search out the records which contains "truck" or "heavy truck", is it easy to implement this?

Comment: @user2574853 this should do the trick `select truckType from table where trackType like '%, truck,% or trackType like '%, heavy truck'`

Comment: yes, I agree with you. But it is more convinent to put the value into another table, and sql statement won't be trick.

Comment: it's upto you. you have to design database as per your requirment.

Comment: be sure to `normalize` your data. i.e. don't store charecter as it is.create a new table which will have `id` related to your `truckType` and the store that id instead of whole charecter which would take more space

Answer (score 0):

you should make a separate table:

```
------------------
typeId | type        |
-----------------
1      | truck       |
2      | heavy truck |
....
```

Also table for entity:

```
------------------
entityid |         |
-----------------
1        | entity1 |
2        | entity2 |
```

and other table will have multiple to one relationship with this table:

```
-------------------------------
id | typeId      | entityId    |
-------------------------------
1  | 1           | 2           |
2  | 2           | 2           |
2  | 2           | 1           |
```

And your select would be a join of this two tables.

Comment: yeah, this solution is exactly the same as what I mentioned in my post. Is there any other way to handle this without additional table?

Comment: Actually you of cource can use Full text search by nvarchar, but I don't think that it is a good way to do such things.

Comment: to @Andriy M - many thanks, for formatting my answer, ho did you do that?

Comment: Nothing to it, just selected pieces of text and pressed Ctrl-K. You can see what that did to your post if you press the `edit` link just below it. There's a toolbar above the post when you are editing it, so you can explore the buttons to see what they do. You can also learn about formatting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it very much