# How to split column using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to split my table column data as below.

original table

```
ID parentID title meta
24    -       E
1    24       A   
2    25       B
3    1        C   1,2,4
4    2        D   1,2,3
```

Now I want to split

```
ID meta title
3   1     A
3   2     B
3   4     D
```

This is what I tried so far

```
  SELECT tbl_sub.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_sub.metakey, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) meta 
  FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers 
  INNER JOIN tbl_sub
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(tbl_sub.metakey)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tbl_sub.meta , ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
  where id=3
  ORDER BY id, n
```

Comment: Do you have a table somewhere of every possible `meta` value?

Comment: @eggyal : im putting meta values as id's. Ex: meta value 1,2 is id of the same table.   meta value 1 is id 1 which the matching title is A likewise

Comment: Try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22669310/1448311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is called `metas`, this query will do what you want.

```
select m2.id, m1.id, m1.title
  from metas m1
    inner join metas m2
      on find_in_set(m1.id, m2.meta);
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3222d/3)

Normally `find_in_set()` is a bit of a crutch around poorly designed tables (which is certainly what this is), but at least you're using it for overall good!

Comment: will it be possible to put another find_in_set ?

Comment: i have edited your fiddle. what i want is another coloum to get title of id s. Ex: id 24 is parent id as well as id , so i want to get the title with matching for id 24 as well . please advice