# Check if value exists in MySQL table and then select [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

Here is my pivot table `project_group`:

```
+-----+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| ids | group_id | project_id | admin_id | user_id |
+-----+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|   4 |      115 |          1 |        1 | [3,4,5] |
|   5 |      115 |          2 |        1 | [5,2,1] |
|   6 |      115 |          3 |        1 | [1,3,6] |
```

This table represent group linked to the projects....`user_id` is which users can see projects/group... Is there any way to display correct projects/group only to the users defined in `user_id`?

Also content in `user_id` field can be changed....

Comment: yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: Basically resuting from some bad database design. Dont store data like that

Comment: you should have another table with 3 columns. id(auto_incremented), project_id, user_id. Then you do joins, and selects with the results.

Comment: Do you think to add project_user pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to first normalize your database. Storing comma separated lists in a cell is allowed, but generally bad practice, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

If you can have multiple users per project, you should have a linking table with a column for project and a column for user, like this:

```
project_users:
| project_id | user_id |
```

and you can make (project_id, user_id)  a composite primary key.

That way, you can select the users for a project (say, project 1) like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM project_users
WHERE project_id = 1;
```

Once you have these, you can display the project data only to users whose `id` is returned in the above list.

I have built an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a398/2) that helps demonstrate this visually, if it helps.

It is good to note that this proper normalization gives the opportunity to a lot of useful data as well, as it becomes easier to search for users by project, but also you can search for project information based on a user.

Comment: Thanks! After I change database how can I select projects/group with Laravel 5 for user that is currently logged?

Comment: Is that possible because I have 2 pivot table project_user, project_group?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: For example user with id `3` is logged into the system and he should get on the home page name of project with id 1 and 3 (look from table above).... How to create query for that with Laravel 5?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Laravel, but you can get projects 1 and 3 by using `SELECT * FROM project_users WHERE user_id = 3`. Hope that pushes you in the right direction!

Comment: Also I think I will have problem with `FOREIGN KEY` because I use MyISAM

Comment: That's possible, it was just for demonstration purposes. You don't have to use that.

Comment: Is ok to store json to MySQL?