# MySQL WHERE LIKE multiple criteria

Tags: mysql

I have the following example table and attributes:

```
---------------------------
|  Name  |       Town     |
---------------------------
| Name 1 |      POOLE     |
| Name 2 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
| Name 3 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
| Name 4 |      POOLE     |
---------------------------
```

I am using the following SQL statement in PHP to retrieve rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Town` LIKE '%".$global->getPlayerTown()."%'
```

Given the criteria `POOLE` the database returns:

```
---------------------------
|  Name  |       Town     |
---------------------------
| Name 1 |      POOLE     |
| Name 2 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
| Name 3 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
| Name 4 |      POOLE     |
---------------------------
```

However when using the criteria `POOLE/WALLASEY` the query returns:

```
---------------------------
|  Name  |       Town     |
---------------------------
| Name 2 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
| Name 3 | POOLE/WALLASEY |
---------------------------
```

How do I intelligently tell the PHP to split the string into separate criteria (i.e. `POOLE` and `WALLASEY`) in one query, so that the query retrieves all rows?

Comment: explode town string on `/`, build individual `like` clauses with the exploded parts, build new sql string... or just normalize the data in the tables

Comment: @MarcB table isn't fully normallised, I understand. However, could you give me an example of the exploded query?

Comment: Vote for normalizing. This way you are (obviously) limited while searching database.

Comment: it'd end being `where foo like '%poole%' (and/or, depending on your needs) foo like '%wallasey%'`, e.g. one `like` clause for every town name in your search string.

Comment: Only problem with that is both `POOLEVILLE` and `POOLE` would match. Yuck. Also, what if a user enters a town that actually has multiple names separated by a slash (e.g. using country `Netherlands/Holland`)? It's not likely, but possible. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `town` REGEXP 'POOLE|WALLASEY';
```

This will match any rows that has one or more instances of POOLE or WALLASEY.

As to the PHP side, depending on how many kinds of separators ('/' in this case) you have in your dataset, it can get rather messy rather quickly.
But replace '/' with '|' in getPlayerTown() would seem to be one way of doing it.

As to performance, I'm not sure how REGEXP is as opposed to LIKE.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: We only have `/` fortunately!

Answer (score 3):

This is an iteration of an often-asked class of questions: *How do I select on a single datum, if I have more than one in a field?*

The answer, as always, is: *You don't.*

There are many reasons for that, but one of the most important is performance: Basically a `LIKE '%...'` can't use an index. That might be ok with a handful of test rows, but it quickly becomes a problem when scaling.

The only reliable ways are to

- either normalize your data
- or use a fulltext index

In your case I'd strongly vote for normalization: Create a `towns` table, then link it to the players via a join table. You can now search for any town with full index use, finding the players through the join.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the example I am giving is a condensed version of my table, the data is out of my control as is imported from a csv, so I have no way of normalising.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B stated, using [explode](http://php.net/explode).

```
<?php
$array = explode("/",$global->getPlayerTown());

foreach($array as $Town){
  $list = $list ."'%" .$Town ."%', ";
}

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Town` LIKE ANY(" .$list .")";
?>
```

Please go the smart route and normalize your data. This idea may work, but that doesn't mean it is the best choice.

Comment: Side note: You're probably better off linking to the official docs than w3schools: http://php.net/explode

Comment: @Mike yes I am, thanks for catching that haha. Fixed it.

Comment: @Ryan_W4588, just tried this and it returns an empty result?

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the towns, then loop through them and build the query like so:

```
$towns = explode('/', $global->getPlayerTown());
$first = true;
$like_sql = '';
foreach($towns as $town) {
    $like_sql .= $first ? ' WHERE ' : ' OR ';
    $like_sql .= "`Town` LIKE '%{$town}%'";
    $first = false;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` {$like_sql}";
```

However I would recommend you normalise your data, and have a separate towns table, with a user_town pivot table.