# Sql + php join and explode

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables on my mysql database :
- restaurant
- restaurant_type

restaurant has 3 column : `id`, `idtype`, `name`

> Example :
>
> - 1, 1-2, Restaurant name
> - 2, 2-3-5, Restaurant name

restaurant_type has 2 column : `idtype`, `typename`

> Example :
>
> 1. Salad
> 2. Burger
> 3. Steak house
> 4. Japanese
> 5. French fries

For that moment, my sql request is :

```
mysql_query("select distinct 
                restaurant.idtype,
                restaurant_type.idtype,
                restaurant_type.typename 
                from restaurant,restaurant_type 
                where restaurant.idtype=restaurant_type.idtype 
                order by restaurant_type.typename");
```

But I don't know how can I add explode function to search different `idtype`.

An idea to help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: There is no equivalent of `explode` in mysql and other solutions for attempting similar are, to be honest, very messy ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query ). You would be better creating a third table to do lookups - one that holds the restaurant id and the types

Comment: If you store comma separated values within your `restaurant` tables column `idtype` than you can simply use `FIND_IN_SET` function of MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table scheme is wrong. You're treating a N:M relation (restaurant <--> Type) as 1:N which is not. So instead of 2 tables, you need 3:

- restaurant(`id`, `name`)
- type(`id`, `name`)
- restaurant_type(`id_restaurant`, `id_type`)

Example data:

> ```
> Restaurant
> ==========
> 1, restaurant name 1
> 2, restaurant name 2
>
> Type
> ====
> 1, Salad
> 2, Burguer
> 3, Steak House
> 4, Japanese
> 5, French Fries
>
> Restaurant type
> ===============
> 1, 1
> 1, 2
> 2, 2 
> 2, 3
> 2, 5
> ```

And then your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT restaurant.name, type.name
FROM restaurant,restaurant_type 
WHERE restaurant.id = restaurant_type.id_restaurant and restaurant_type.id_type = type.id
ORDER BY type.name
```