# Comma Separated values into rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, split, rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT jp.skills
FROM job_profile jp
UNION
SELECT js.skills
FROM job_seeker_profile js
```

**The result:**

```
|skills              |
|php                 |
|PHP,Jquery,MVC      | 
|java                |
|.net                |   
|Tally               | 
|php, mysql, yii     |
|css, html, bootstrap|
|javascript, json    |
```

but I need this as each item as row (each comma separated values as rows)

**Expected result:**

```
|skills   | 
|yii      |
|PHP      | 
|Jquery   |
|MVC      |
|.net     |   
|Tally    | 
|bootstrap|
|css      |
|html     |
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: check this mysql function if it address your requirement 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Mysql Split a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

Comment: Ok I use this `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(jp.skills , ',', js.skills ), ',', -1) value
  FROM job_profile jp ,job_seeker_profile js
 WHERE js.skills <= 1 + (LENGTH(jp.skills) - LENGTH(REPLACE(js.skills , ',', '')))
 ORDER BY value` But returns empty result :(

Comment: links shared not helps!!I mean in my issues!

Answer (score 0):

Create a split function which will split the data on , then create row wise data

```
SELECT distinct  Split.fn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS skills  
 FROM  
 (SELECT  CAST ('<a>' + REPLACE(skills, ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AS Data  
  FROM  job_profile
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/a') AS Split(fn);
```

**Note:** Update the inner query according to your need

**Updated** : In your case query will be

```
SELECT distinct  Split.fn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS skills  
 FROM  
 (SELECT  CAST ('<a>' + REPLACE(jp.skills, ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AS Data  
  FROM  job_profile jp
  UNION
    SELECT js.skills
    FROM job_seeker_profile js
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/a') AS Split(fn);
```

Comment: Confusing.. Is this query is Right: `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(jp.skills , ',', js.skills ), ',', -1) value
  FROM job_profile jp ,job_seeker_profile js
 WHERE js.skills <= 1 + (LENGTH(jp.skills) - LENGTH(REPLACE(js.skills , ',', '')))
 ORDER BY value'

Comment: This query is also very confusing

Comment: Please let me know what is the confusion about query shared in answer, will help you to understand that.

Comment: Lookout my query in the Question ,im combining two tables and showing it in a row.So im bit confused about how to apply your query?

Comment: @Jackhad Updated in answer