# How to Split String {} with Multiple Values

Tags: sql, json, presto

Let's say that I have a type STRING column 'debugdata'. An example value for a given user looks like this:

```
{"TITLE_DESCRIPTION":"approve","CATEGORY":"approve"}
```

However, let's say there can be multiple values for the TITLE_DESCRIPTION

```
{"TITLE_DESCRIPTION":"No, name does not match,No, summary is not clear","CATEGORY":"Yes"}
```

How can I split out the "No, name does not match" and "No, summary is not clear" into two columns?

I've tried using `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_ARRAY_GET` and other JSON syntax, but I can't quite break this up into two columns. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto - duplicate of **_MySQL_** post?

Comment: This does not make much sense. Why would you split it only on the 2nd  comma? Think what would happen with other `"TITLE_DESCRIPTION"` values that contain multiple commas.

Answer (score 0):

lets say x is your map from your example

```
let x = {"TITLE_DESCRIPTION":"No, name does not match,No, summary is not clear","CATEGORY":"Yes"}
```

so all you need to do is this:

```
let b = (x.TITLE_DESCRIPTION).split(',')
```

edit: in you example you split the sentences with ',' but have ',' in the string himself so use char escape for ',' or use other char for split the sentences and send it to the split function instead of ','.

Comment: This is not an SQL answer nor what the OP requested (which is unclear by itself)

Answer (score 0):

What about first use `json_extract` and then use the String function `split`?

Comment: This is not an answer