# Get value from a table where field value has stored separated by comma using codeigniter

Tags: php, database

This is  my communication_posting table

[image]

Into fields 2,3 are user_id in user_master table. This is my user_master table (used for login ).

[image]

I want to get session_id means store in to column in communication_posing table but here two session_id (mean user_id) has store how to get only one from them.

Comment: here i run this query but it shows an error,my query is-

Comment: SELECT content FROM t_communication_posting WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,to)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in two seperate queries, you can use php `explode()`.

```
$explode_array = explode(',', $database_result['to']);
$value_you_want = $explode_array[0];
```

If you need to do this in SQL, create a split function in MySQL. This question has some answers that will help.

[Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)