# How to return the REGEXP matches in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

MySQL provides [REGEXP a.k.a. RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) for matching regular expressions.

How do I list the positions of the matches?

For instance, for a table with contents

```
X       | Y
--------+---------------
abcd    | abaab
efgh    | ababbaaabaaaab
```

I would like to be able to write something that takes `Y` and `aa*b` as arguments and returns all matches of the regexp `aa*b` in column `Y`, like this:

```
X       | POS   | LEN
--------+-------+-------
abcd    | 1     | 2
abcd    | 2     | 2
efgh    | 1     | 2
efgh    | 3     | 2
efgh    | 6     | 4
efgh    | 10    | 5
```

How can this be done?

Thus far, the best I can think of is a dirty workaround: try matching every possible substring, like is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql), and based on that, generate multiple results, either [by using a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows), or [by generating and executing INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query).

Is there a saner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 has [REGEXP_INSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) for this.

Earlier versions of MySQL don't have that function.

The most common workaround is to return the query result including the full string that matches your regular expression — without knowing the position where it matches — and use some more feature-rich text matching functions in your favorite application language to find the position.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.