# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax - STRING_SPLIT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT er.pNumber, er.name, ep.fPosition, eo.res
FROM events_shot er, events_shot_final ep, events_shot_final_res eo, events_gear era
WHERE era.idShot=er.idShot AND ep.idPhoto=era.idPhoto AND eo.idShot=era.idShot
    AND era.idShot=42 AND eo.shotType='PRT'
    AND er.pNumber IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(eo.photosId,'-')
        )
```

**shotsId** is a String like 12-1-8-7... with n **pNumber** id separated by '-'

Unfortunately the query return this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(eo.photosId,'-')   )' at line 7

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: That function is used in SQL Server 2016, not in MySQL.

Comment: eo.combination does not appear in the code above! Are you sure it's the same code? But yes STRING_SPLIT does not exist in mysql. [Here's a list of mySQL string functions you can use](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: You're using a SQL Server function in MySQL, and you're giving an error message from a different query.  In coding of any kind, attention to detail pays vast rewards.

Comment: If you have any control, change the database design.  Putting multiple values in a delimited string breaches all sorts of SQL principles.  The correct design is to have a separate row for each value *(search for normal form)*.  Then you don't have to mess around with splitting strings, and you can make use of indexes and constraints *(plus 1001 other benefits)*.

Comment: (Unrelated) Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: guys I can't change the database. How can I change my query?

Comment: @ADyson sorry i did a mistake when I reported the Error. But how can I change my query? Do you know a solution with mysql functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429324/string-split-in-mysql-how-to-do-it

Comment: @Diego "Do you know a solution with mysql functions?"...I gave you a link to all the mysql string functions, so you can read about them and decide which one to use. Didn't you look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match using a regex rather than splitting a string, replace the code that gives you an error with

```
AND REGEXP_INSTR(eo.photosId, CONCAT('-?', er.pNumber, '-?')) > 0
```

*Update*

Instead of trying to match dash-number-dash the below regex matches not number-number-not number to match only the exact number given

```
AND REGEXP_INSTR(eo.photosId, CONCAT('(^|[^0-9])', er.pNumber, '([^0-9]|$)')) > 0
```

Comment: @Diego Of all comments and answers, you chose the wrong one. This will return a match regardless of the `-` and other characters. It will match `56` in `123-456-789`. It will match `56` in `123 456 789`. It will match `56` in `123456789`.

Comment: @GSerg thank you, unfortunately I can't test the code in this moment, and I must find a solution as soon as possible

Comment: @Diego I have added a second version that is more exact and you don't need to change your data for it to work properly.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson MySql [does not recognize `\d`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax). So your expression still matches `56` in `123456789`.

Comment: @GSerg, sloppy of me. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad database structure, `eo.photosId` should be a separate table.

But you have an extremely suboptimal solution without changing the DB structure:

```
AND concat('%-', er.pNumber,'-%') LIKE concat('-', eo.photosId, '-')
```

you must change `12-1-8-7` to `-12-1-8-7-` and find ID with delimiter `-1-` + `%` - LIKE any char operator