# STRING_SPLIT in MySql- how to do it?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT er.pNumber, er.name, ep.fPosition, eo.res
FROM events_shot er, events_shot_final ep, events_shot_final_res eo, events_gear era
WHERE era.idShot=er.idShot AND ep.idPhoto=era.idPhoto AND eo.idShot=era.idShot
    AND era.idShot=42 AND eo.shotType='PRT'
    AND er.pNumber IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(eo.photosId,'-')
        )
```

**shotsId** is a String like 12-1-8-7... with n **pNumber** id separated by '-'

Unfortunately the query return this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(eo.photosId,'-')   )' at line 7

I can't change the database, how can I change my query?

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Don't start a new account to ask the same question again... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428328/error-code-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-string-split

Answer (score -2):

Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column.

Learn proper SQL syntax!  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

With that said, you don't need to split the string.  You can use string operations:

```
AND CONCAT('-', eo.photosId, '-') LIKE CONCAT('%-', er.pNumber, '-%')
```

But you should really start work on fixing the data model as soon as you get this query to work.