# database : related fields contain multiple value

Tags: sql, database

Here's the table1 :

```
| code | fruit  |
|  1   | Orange |
|  2   | Apple  |
|  3   | Grape  |
|  4   | Mango  |
```

Here's the table2 :

```
| name   | fruitcode |
| Jack   | 1, 3      |
| Alice  | 2         |
| Emma   | 1, 2, 4   |
```

My question is, can `table2.fruitcode` which contains numbers relate to `table1.code` ?

Comment: No, you should normalise your database.

Comment: Normalize your database. Read up on how to model a [many-to-many](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql+many+to+many) table relationship in your DBMS.

Comment: some people say `WHERE field REGEXP ',?[SEARCHED-VALUE],?';` [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query#answer-10953029)

Answer (score 0):

If by *relate* you mean to join the tables, you can use the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator:

```
select *
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on concat(',', replace(t2.fruitcode, ' ', ''), ',') like concat('%,', t1.code, ',%')
```

Most databases support the functions [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).
But this is just a solution for the specific problem.
Soon you will face problems that can't be dealt with such simple tricks.
The best solution is to normalize your tables from the start.